# Using Google Maps API in an iframe to prevent CSS conflicts?

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe, conflict

Is there an easy way to use the Google Maps API so that the map is displayed in an iframe and not inline? I would like to do this because [some WordPress templates have CSS rules that are applied to the Google Maps elements too](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28189/google-maps-and-yandex-maps-doesnt-work-correctly), giving weird results. One example with the current default theme: images in post content get a `max-width` of 97.5%, which gives these gaps between map tiles:

[image: Google Maps with grey gaps between tiles]

Assume this is for a plugin that will be used in different themes, so I have no control over the base CSS. I think there are three ways to solve this:

1. Add extra CSS rules in my plugin that reset all possible base rules that can conflict (hard to do, there are so many weird settings in the wild - `max-width: 97.5%` is only one).
2. Ask Google to add more `!important` rules in their CSS to prevent these kind of conflicts (just as hard, and Google may not be willing to do this)
3. Just put the map in an iframe

If you have a better suggestion to prevent these conflicts I would like to know them.

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as putting the map in the iframe, setting the iframe size to the map size, and removing the iframe border with `frameborder=0`

---

Edit: You will also have to remove the padding/margin on the map page.

**map_page.html**

```
html, body { margin: 0, padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Would this work with an empty iframe (`src="about:blank"`), so that I can keep all my logic in the main frame?